# Declaring class differently for different Dojo versions without duplicating code?

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-connections

I have an iWidget designed for IBM Connections, and my javascript code depends on Dojo (which is included by default in Connections).
It currently works in Connections 4.0 and 4.5, but is broken in Connections 5.0 (released last week), as Dojo has been updated to v1.9 and complains about my use of `dojo.require`.

These messages appear in the browser console when my widget tries to load on Connections 5.0:

```
Avoid calling dojo.require() to load classes at runtime, use net.jazz.ajax.xdloader.load_async() instead. Function '(anonymous)' required class 'dojox.atom.io.model'.
Avoid calling dojo.require() to load classes at runtime, use net.jazz.ajax.xdloader.load_async() instead. Function '(anonymous)' required class 'dojox.atom.io.Connection'.
```

I want to make conditional code that uses different ways of defining my widget class and requiring other Dojo modules depending on the Dojo version.

The widget javascript currently looks like this:

```
dojo.provide('insightCommunityWidgetClass');
dojo.require('dojox.atom.io.model');
dojo.require('dojox.atom.io.Connection');

dojo.declare('insightCommunityWidgetClass',null,{
    // Class fields and methods. Currently 680 lines uncompressed.
});
```

I haven't yet created a version that works with Dojo 1.9 / Connections 5.0, but I think it would look something like this (and I'll have to make my javascript file name match the desired class name):

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare','dojox.atom.io.model','dojox.atom.io.Connection'], function(declare){
    return declare(null, {
        // Class fields and methods.
    });
});
```

How can I have both of these in one file and choose between them without duplicating the class body?

**Update:**
I've attempted some conditional code, checking `(define && define.amd)` as suggested by Dimitri, tested this on Connections 4.0 and 4.5, and am getting very weird behaviour.

Temporarily ignoring any attempt to not duplicate my class, here's some conditional code which I've used exactly as shown, with a severely reduced widget class:

```
if (define && define.amd) {
    console.log('Declaring insightWidgetClass with AMD (new method).');
    define(['dojo/_base/declare','dojox/atom/io/model','dojox/atom/io/Connection'],
        function(declare){
            return declare(null,{
                SVC_INV: 1,
                onLoad: function() {
                    console.log('insightWidgetClass onLoad.');
                }
            });
        }
    );

} else {
    console.log('Declaring insightWidgetClass with dojo.declare (old method).');
    dojo.provide('insightWidgetClass');
    dojo.require('dojox.atom.io.model');
    dojo.require('dojox.atom.io.Connection');

    dojo.declare('insightWidgetClass',null,{
        SVC_INV: 1,
        onLoad: function() {
            console.log('insightWidgetClass onLoad.');
        }
    });
}
```

This seems not to run at all. None of my `console.log` messages appear in the browser console.

If I comment out the conditionals and make it so the only active code is the block after `else`, it runs. I get the "declaring ... (old method)" and the "insightWidgetClass onLoad" console messages.

I thought maybe enclosing the Dojo `provide`, `require` and `declare` calls in any kind of block might cause a problem, so I tested just putting the working code in an `if (true) {` block, and it still works.

The last things I've tried at this point are adding this one line before everything else, to see what `define` is:

```
console.log('dojo define',define);
```

... which breaks it. No console messages at all from my code.
Then I remove the `define` argument from that new line, so it's only sending a string to the console, and the code works again.
It seems like *any* mention of a `define` identifier silently stops the rest of the code from running.
There are no errors or warnings in the console indicating a problem. All I can say to that is: WTF?!

Now back to checking `dojo.version` instead.

Comment: Just a suggestion. You could try enclosing dojo version specific code using the `dojo.version` see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/version.html) for details.

Comment: @frank - I know of the `dojo.version` object, but I can't see from that documentation how I can avoid duplicating my entire class body when only the `dojo.provide`, `dojo.require`, and `dojo.declare` lines need to change for different Dojo version.

Comment: There is another module known has `dojo.has`. see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/has.html) for details, which might be useful for your scenario. `dojo.has` can be used as per [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/device_optimized_builds/) tutorial to create **specific builds**. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally both should still work, `dojo.provide()` and `dojo.require()` are deprecated, but not entirely removed. Just make sure that your loading dojo in synchronous mode.

Besides that, the AMD way of coding is introduced in Dojo 1.7, which means that it should be supported on IBM Connections 4.5 as well (though I don't know about IBM Connections 4).

But if you really want to use both code bases, you can simply refer to the same object in stead of duplicating it, for example:

```js
var myModule = {
    // Class fields and methods.
};
if (dojo.version.major == 1 && dojo.version.minor == 9) {
    define(['dojo/_base/declare','dojox.atom.io.model','dojox.atom.io.Connection'], function(declare){
        return declare(null, myModule);
    });
} else {
    dojo.provide('insightCommunityWidgetClass');
    dojo.require('dojox.atom.io.model');
    dojo.require('dojox.atom.io.Connection');

    dojo.declare('insightCommunityWidgetClass',null, myModule);  
}
```

Or you could use the following check:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD style code
} else {
    // Non-AMD style code
}
```

This is the approach most cross-loader libraries use. Libraries that work both on AMD loaders (Dojo, Require.js), but also on Node.js or simply by using global namespacing use a similar piece of code to determine how they load their module.

Comment: I did try doing it like that. It seems the widget framework has a problem with it. There are no errors, but the widget's onLoad method never runs when I write it that way. I'm going to try defining the class as a function with prototyped methods like in point 1.2 of http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class.

Comment: Also noting that checking for `define && define.amd` seems like a good suggestion; better than checking the version numbers.

Comment: @ScottLeis Indeed, I think it's the preferrable way of checking these things. Many libraries do it, for example take a look at Moment.js which does a similar check: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L2723

Comment: I've updated my question with details of a strange issue I had trying to check `define`. I've tried again with setting a class variable (as in your answer) and that now seems to be working in Connections 4.0 and 4.5, so I must've made some error when that solution initially failed. Currently having bigger issues with our Connections 5.0 (Dojo 1.9) environment, so might be a few days before I can confirm the answer.

Comment: In your old code you use `dojo.require()`, in AMD there's a difference between `require()` and `define()`. `define()` only works if the module is later imported inside a `require()` function. So `define()` only works for defining modules, but in order to use that module, you have to `require()` it.

Comment: I expect such an import is done by the widget framework in IBM Connections. I don't know much about that, except to note: (1) An XML file defines the widget, and names the javascript class in the `iScope` attribute of the root element; and (2) the javascript class has this `onLoad` method which I never explicitly call, but that method runs if the widget is set up correctly.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it definitely works on Connections 4.0 and 4.5, and the problems I'm having on Connections 5.0 seem to be with IBM's implementation of Dojo and not directly related to the question.

Comment: A small update, using `if (define && define.amd)` like I mentioned earlier may throw errors because define may not be defined yet. To overcome that issue, a better solution might be the use of the following: `if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)`. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not your code, it should work as it is. We recently faced the same problem and identified the cause.

Connections 5 is using an AMD version of the Jazz framework which provides its own dojo loader. This framework is used to aggregate the needed dojo modules into a single JS file, which limits the number of requests to the server. Unfortunately, this loader no longer handles synchronous modules loading. It fails with the warning you reported when dojo.require() requests a module that is not yet loaded by the aggregator. If the module was already loaded, because it was part of the Jazz aggregated file, then it works. It explains why you can dojo.require() some modules, but not all of them.

-> A workaround is to deploy a server side OSGi bundle to get the modules you need part of the aggregated JS file. There is a documented extension point for this. This can unblock you while enhancing the performance of your page.

Now, we opened a PMR to IBM support. The development team is working on a resolution. We hope that they will be able to deliver a fix soon.

We reported the following issues:

- dojo.require()
- dojo.requireLocalization()
- dojo.registerModulePath()/require({paths:})

If you think about something else, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, Philippe. This is very interesting. I'll keep an eye out for any Connections fixes relating to this.

Comment: As I understood, this should be fixed in C5 CR1, with also an iFix if you need it earlier.